# Map over an array within an object of arrays

Tags: reactjs

I am using a reusable component for React, and I am trying to map over an array within an object of arrays to go inside of this component.
the data looks like:

```
export const portfolioData = [
  {
    title: "Drum Kit",
    url: "some url",
    codeUrl: "some github repo",
    mobileFriendly: false,
    img: "some img",
    techUsed: ["React", "APIs", "Custom Hooks"],
  },
];
```

The map looks like:

```
<div>
               {portfolioData.map((portfolio,i)=>(<PortfolioCard key={i}>{portfolio}</PortfolioCard> ))}
            </div>
```

and the reusable component looks like:

```
 <div>
            <img src={img} />
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <button target="_blank" href={url}><FaCode />
            </button>
            <button target="_blank" href={codeUrl}><CgWebsite />

            </button>
            <ul>
                <li>{mobileFriendly}</li>
                <li>{techUsed}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

When I use .map() it recognises that I have mapped over *something* but it doesn't show anything up on the screen, just three empty components (I have 3 objects in my array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the property values in the object as props, you can spread them into the component.

```
{portfolioData.map((portfolio,i) => <PortfolioCard {...portfolio} key={i} />)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm *just* learning React (in fact did it over the Thanksgiving holiday!) and this was one of the first things I learned.

The issue with your map is that the output produces a `PortfolioCard` component for each item in Array.  Because of that, you have to enclose it in either a `<div>` tag or a `<>` tag.

[I whipped up an example using your code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/delicate-hill-2w6mq3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A32%2C7) that you can try out.

(I can't figure out how the StackOverflow in-page console works, sorry).

Comment: Thanks Mike. Thats really useful information. What I did to get my code to work was to add {...portfolio} to the return from the map. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

I modified your array as it was missing this `]`

```
export const portfolioData = [
  {
    title: "Drum Kit",
    url: "some url",
    codeUrl: "some github repo",
    mobileFriendly: false,
    img: "some img",
    techUsed: ["React", "APIs", "Custom Hooks"],
  },
];
```

Next, Mapped `portfolioData` with the `PortfolioCard` component while passing the `portfolioData` object as a prop to `PortfolioCard`

```
 <div>
    {portfolioData.map((portfolio, i) => (
      <PortfolioCard key={i} portfolio={portfolio} />
     ))}
 </div>
```

After that, modify your `PortfolioCard` component to take in a prop `portfolio` and use it through out the entire component below:

```
function PortfolioCard({ portfolio }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={portfolio.img} alt="img" />
      <h3>{portfolio.title}</h3>
      <a target="_blank" href={portfolio.url}>
        <FaCode />
      </a>
      <a target="_blank" href={portfolio.codeUrl}>
        <CgWebsite />
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>{portfolio.mobileFriendly}</li>
        <li>
          {portfolio.techUsed.map((item, i) => (
            <span key={i}>{item}x</span>
          ))}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```